# Is there any way to use Cassandra datastax mapper with inheritance?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using `cassandra java datastax 2.1`; I have been trying to use its mapper class to save a class which is subclass of some other class, and I am having a hard time figuring that out.

What I have found so far is if `classB` is subclass of `classA`, and if I am trying to save `classB` using mapper then:

1. All the partition keys fields should be in subclass i.e `classB`.
2. Only the fields in `classB` are being saved.

Am I doing something wrong or is there no way to use inheritance with Java `datastax` driver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also asked this question here: [Datastax Cassandra - Inheritance when using object mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949827/datastax-cassandra-inheritance-when-using-object-mapper)

I found a solution that I proposed in the respective ticket:
https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-541

Therefore you need to import the `com.datastax.driver.mapping.AnnotationParser` class to your project (overriding the existing class) and change line 74

```
 for (Field field : entityClass.getDeclaredFields())
```

to

```
for (Field field : entityClass.getFields())
```

If this is a good, bullet proof or long lasting solution I can't promise, but for my use case it did the job.

If you are interested in a official implementation of such a feature upvote the ticket (https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-541).